# When is it valid for me to just integrate a trig function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I am having a problem identifying when I need to use some kind of integration technique or am I just over complicating things. Could someone please explain to me when I need to or not?

Normally, I would just integrate as normal when the problem is like this

$$\int \cos(x) dx = \sin(x) + c$$

But when things become like the following, I don't have rules to fall back on and just rely on memory and experience of solving problems.

$$\iiint \cos(x+y+z) dz dx dy$$

$$\int \sin(2x) dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the ordinary rules
and treat the variables that you are not
integrating with respect to as constants.

For example, the general forms are
$\int_u^v f(x+a)dx = \int_{u+a}^{v+a} f(y) dy$
(with $y = x-a$)
and $\int_u^v f(cx)dx = (1/c)\int_{cu}^{cv} f(y) dy$
(with $y = x/c$).

If the integrals are indefinite,
these become
$\int f(x+a)dx = \int f(y) dy$
and $\int f(cx)dx = (1/c)\int f(y) dy$.

Putting these in your examples,
$\int \cos(x+y+z) dz = \sin(x+y+z)$,
since the "$x+y$" is a just a constant here,
and
$\int \sin(2x) dx = (1/2)\int \sin(y) dy
\text{ (with } y = 2x)
= (1/2) (-\cos(y))
= (-1/2) \cos(2x)
$.

For the iterated integral, keep doing this
until you run out of integrals.